# Do web browsers download faster than your max bandwidth?

Tags: browser, compression, bandwidth

Since content is compressed on transmission and uncompressed on the browser, does that make the transfer rate faster than your bandwidth? Or is there another term for this?

For example, a 1GB white space text file could be downloaded to your computer extremely quickly because it is compressed to a very small size and very little data is transferred

[How gzip compression works](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/gzip)

Comment: Where did you read that a browser can compress and uncompress traffic?  1GB of data is 1GB of data.  If you can only download 5KB of data it will take the same amount of time if its compressed or uncompressed.

Comment: @Ramhound - I added a link

Comment: gzip really is only used when the original data isn't compressed.  But as I indicate 5Kb of data will take the same amount of time if its compressed or not compressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relatively talking, yes. But speed is measured in terms of the **data it actually transfers**, it doesn't matter if it's compressed or uncompressed.

For example, if a 1 GB text file is compressed to 100 KB and transferred from an FTP server to your browser in just 1 second and then uncompressed back to the original 1 GB, it actually just transferred 100 KB of data through the connection in 1 second and therefore the speed was 100 KB/s. If that 100 KB become 1 GB once uncompressed is another story. There is no magic here.

Comment: This is the real answer, other comments just talk about how wrong is the OP supposition but doesn't really talk about the true question.

Answer (score 3):

Your max throughput is your max throughput. Doesnt matter what the data is, frames are frames, packets are packets (this is a big simplification, but anyways).

Compression just makes better use of the current connection, doesnt make it any faster.